# How to analyse GarbageCollections

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, garbage-collection

in my wpf application I have the following behavior of GC and ProcessMemory.

[image]

These are the first 10 sec. and as you can see I have many calls of the GC. For me it looks like there are many small objects that are created on start, but don't really needed by the program.
How can I analyse what's happen or is this behavior normal?

Comment: As long as it doesn't chunk your general IO Performance (but: 650MB Process Memory) you might want to ignore it. This software already seems to be very complex - and the amount of GC'ing looks healthy. As long as there is no evident issue, you might want to keep it that way.

Comment: For my opinion the application takes to much time to start, and the question is how many time is occupied by the GC?

Comment: Thats a valid concern then. I can't see the time take (assuming 30+ seconds now). Start here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650691.aspx

Comment: 650 MB process memory usage is quite lot so this number of GC collections generally looks ok to me. Consider using some performance monitoring tool. One of free options would be [perfView](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/10/09/improving-your-apps-performance-with-perfview/). Looks old-schoolish but gives you everything you need.

Comment: "don't really needed" is not a valid assumption.  Use a memory profiler to discover what is getting allocated.

Comment: Thank you all for you input. It seems that all the memory and GC is coming from EntityFramework. Maybe I must rethink about what I want the user to see at startup.

Answer (score 0):

Full garbage collections are very expensive, so the .NET framework makes use of 3 different partial collections: generation 0, 1 and 2. Generation 0 garbage collections are the most frequest, generation 1 less so and genertaion 2 the least often. The number of Garbage Collector collections is not usually an issue, this is determined and optimised by the Garbage Collector and shouldn't be fiddled with. There can be a great number of generation 0 collections per generation 1, the same with generation 1 and 2. This is how it's meant to operate.

What can cause an issue is many objects surviving a lower generation collection and being promoted to a higher one. For example using a lot of IDisposable types. On a generation 0 collection an IDisposable is not collected, instead it is marked for generation 1 collection (as the Dispose() has to execute before it can be collected). As generation 1 collections are much less frequent you do not want a lot of objects surviving generation 0 collections because they'll hog memory for longer. Likewise you do not want generation 1 objects being promoted into generation 2 collections, which are even more infrequent.

You can use the Windows Performance Monitor to check the ratio of the garbage collector runs. The performance conters are found under the .NET CLR Memory section.

[image: PerformanceMonitorGCCounters]